# how do to pass '&' symbol inside value in URL?

Tags: php, url, encoding

I was passing the query to my search results page with variable: `?s=`.

I was testing the site and I discovered than when the query has a `&` symbol in it, when I try to retrieve `$_GET['s']` it gets cut in the & symbol.

I tried with `&` and also converting it to `%26` and I'm still having the same problem.

How can I encode them to pass them in URL?

EDIT:

I pointed that I tried encoding it to `%26` and it still didn't work.

I tried with `urlencode()` and on `?s=pizza%26pasta` when I `print_r($_GET)` I get:

```
Array ( [s] => pizza [pasta] => )
```

EDIT 2:

I just found out that the problem actually has to do with `.htaccess` it seems to transform the '&something' in '&something='. No idea how to fix it in htaccess.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

# rewrite to action
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /a/?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: have you tried the urlencode()

Comment: so you want all the statement after "&" also at one GET?

Comment: I have a feeling there is something missing from your details. You actually made me double check this, and I can confirm both locally and on one of my servers using a URI with `%26` does not split the variables.

Comment: `.htaccess`: Yes, either that or the actual server config, `httpd.conf`.

Comment: Please post your `.htaccess QSA flag`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Url encoding the amersand (&) to `%26` is the correct way to do this.

Using `http://yoursite.com?var1=this%26that&var2=other` will result in your `$_GET` superglobal array having two variables

```
$_GET['var1'] = 'this&that';
$_GET['var2'] = 'other';
```

You can use the function [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) to automatically encode all characters that require encoding. These are typically the characters that are used to make up the component parts of a url. i.e. the At symbol (@), colon (:), question mark (?), etc.

```
var_dump(urlencode('one&two'));

string(9) "one%26two"
```

Comment: I just found the problem, it's .htaccess that seems to malwork using the real path works fine. I accept any ideas to fix it, I'm writing a foreach in php to patch it in the meantime.

Comment: You should probably put your `.htaccess` in the question.

Comment: I just added it I belive the problem is there since if I go to write `/a/?s=a&b` on the url it doesn't cut the value in &. But when I go to `/a&b` and let .htaccess redirect it does cut it

Comment: Yes of course it does, because `/a&b` is a **path**, not a **query string**. In this case the webserver decodes in order to see if the file exists.

Comment: but `.htaccess` is turning the path into a query string. Do you mean it decodes it first and then turns it into a query still decoded?

Comment: @Liso22 exactly. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791584/htaccess-and-26-both-splitting-get

Comment: it seems I just need to add the B flag. I'm trying everything but I can't make it work. Could you tell me where I must add the B flag? It would answer the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use these steps:

1. First build your string in PHP
2. Then use the function **urlencode()** to correctly encode your string.
3. When using **$_GET[]** make sure you use **urldecode()** to get the variable to its original format.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You do not need to use `urldecode` on variables in `$_GET`. They are decoded by the parsing engine.

Comment: I just found the problem, it's .htaccess QSA flag that seems to malwork. I accept any ideas to fix it, I'm writing a foreach in php to patch it in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

This is a raw patch I built that takes the array and looks for blank keys and merges them on a string. It only works when a single variable is passed though.

```
function arrayToString($array) {
    $string = '';
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if($value) {
            $string = $string.'&'.$value;
            } else {
            $string = $string.'&'. $key;
            }
        }
    return substr($string,1,strlen($string));
    }
```

---

This is for more than one variable in case someone finds it useful:

```
   function arrayToString($array) {
        $string = '';
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if($value) {
                $string = $string.'&'.$key.'='.$value;
                } else {
                $string = $string.'&'. $key;
                }
            }
        return substr($string,1,strlen($string));
        }
    return $string
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want send following string into your url:

```
var1 = "1st Class Ink & Toner"
var2 = "Test1"
var3 = "test3"
```

Now using php,

```
var1 = urlencode(var1); left remain the same.
```

then put them into url: http://url.com/x=var1&y=var2&z=var3

vKj